# Materialize full width slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I use materializecss to create a slider.
However the image is full width, but not full height(its more than full height, so i get scrollbars). What do i need to change to make the slider fill out my screen with no scrollbars? I also use `$('.slider').slider({full_width: true});`

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <!-- some stuff-->
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="carousel carousel-slider center">
        <a class="carousel-item"><img class="responsive-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/1"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide scrollbars then add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To container which is having the scroll

Comment: Can you please create a JsFiddle for it

Comment: Just checked it at http://materializecss.com/carousel.html#one! and overflow: hidden is working fine, There might be some other issue with your code. That is not related to materializecss

Comment: yes . I recreated it on fiddle with the exact same size http://fiddle.jshell.net/xdrL9e83/357/ but the image is now smaller than the screen....

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct JavaScript?

On Materialize's site (I've used Materialize before, and thought something looked off about your code) it has this as the way to initialize a slider as "full_width:"

```
$('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({full_width: true});
```

In fact, your slider doesn't even have the .slider class; it only has .carousel-slider and .carousel.

I'm thinking if you use the above JavaScript you should be alright.

Comment: ups my bad, thats just a typo :(